# File not found using Task Scheduler

Tags: c#, scheduled-tasks

In my **C# code**, I reference to an XML file **"file.xml"**, which is in the same directory as the executable itself, using XmlDocument.

The application runs perfectly well in VS, but when I try to run the application using Task Scheduler, I get a `System.IO.FileNotFoundException`, even though everything's the same.

I reference to the file using `@".\file.xml"`. Is this some weird stuff specific to Task Scheduler? Appropriate permissions are used.

Comment: Have you set the working directory of the task?

Comment: The program probably runs with a different *current working directory* under Task Scheduler, than it does when you're testing it.

Answer (score 30):

Try to set startup directory for the task. You can set in Task Scheduler.

`Select Task -> Right Click -> Properties -> Actions Tab -> Select Action -> Edit -> Start in (optional)`

Comment: This is *THE ANSWER* and should be marked as such :)

Comment: How can we Mark this Answer.

Answer (score 7):

I met the same problem, and i tried to print out the various path that .Net sets for the program, here's the result on my machine

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory: <my program folder>
Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();: C:\Windows\system32
Environment.CurrentDirectory: C:\Windows\system32
```

so you probably want to use `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` to locate your file, like this:

```
string path = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "file.xml");
// use this path to open xml and do your work with it
```

Comment: I like this answer better than the one above. While the above answer will likely fix the problem for most, it is a "band-aid" fix. The real solution is to fix the invalid file path. Thanks @weidi

Comment: I were using this method, likewise I had to define the base directory in the task scheduler

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the application's *current working directory* to the correct path. I don't know what it is when Task Scheduler launches your application, but it's never a good idea to assume.

You can do so with [`Directory.SetCurrentDirectory()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.setcurrentdirectory.aspx).

Alternatively, you can use an *absolute path* to the XML file.

Answer (score 0):

Try refering to your document by using

```
Application.StartupPath(@"\file.xml")
```

Comment: Is this Windows Forms? How is it relevant?