# SharePoint job fails from Task Scheduler

Tags: sharepoint, scheduled-tasks

I've got a .NET core application that run fine from a command prompt and creates SharePoint Sites and adds content types from templates. When I schedule it to run via Windows Scheduled Tasks with the same account it fails with the following error:

Error applying client template: The Provisioning Template URI MyTemplate.xml is not valid.

What would cause it to not run properly when scheduled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it has nothing to do with SharePoint it is the Task Scheduler. Needs the proper settings in action for the directory/folder

```
Select Task -> Right Click -> Properties -> Actions Tab -> Select Action -> Edit -> Start in (optional)
```

See SO post here:
[File not found using Task Scheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21476149/file-not-found-using-task-scheduler)