# How to Schedule Console Application C#

Tags: c#, console

I have created a Console Application where I've added Microsoft.AnalysisServices dll. I want this App to be Scheduled for every 30 minutes.

I've Published the Application but when I give setup.exe path in Windows Task Scheduler, the task not runs

When I give the applicationname.exe path from the bin/Debug Folder, the application runs

reference: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/manas1/console-application-using-windows-scheduler/

but I don't want to carry the project folder to the Production server, I need a single exe/setup file

I have also tried copying application.exe file from bin folder on desktop but it throws exception 'cannot find Microsoft.AnalysisServices', here is the Screen shot:

[image]

Please Help

Comment: Keep it simple: Forget about Publish Application - just copy the whole contents of your Debug or Release folder (depending on which build you run) to a folder of your choice and set this path in Task Scheduler.

Comment: @Filburt I've copied all the files in a folder & then schedule the exe from that folder, it worked fine for me, it first time ran successfully but 2nd time there's a message in task scheduler: The instance of this task in already running

Comment: Is this the old classic, sheldured task excuted from a different context, or user doesn't have the right to access the folder/file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [File not found using Task Scheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21476149/file-not-found-using-task-scheduler)

Comment: Btw we almost never need picture of things. Error message are alway usefull in question. And for simple question like this an [Mcve] of a 4 lines programme loading a file is more usefull that a picture.

Comment: Or is the question about how to publish deploy a C# console application

Comment: @Filburt your solution worked for me. please add this as answer

Comment: @AlinaAnjum Added as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a (simple) console application, the easiest solution is to use what Microsoft propagated right from the start of .Net: "xcopy deployment".

Depending on your build target (Debug or Release) take everything from the [project dir]\bin\Debug or [project dir]\bin\Release and copy it to a application folder of your choice.

In your Scheduled Task, reference the executable in this application folder.

You can streamline your deployment by adding an automated copy task as a Post-Build task to your project configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy the whole output folder (publish artifact). You can omit things like the pdb files or xml documentations... You can also use tools like ILMerge to merge dependencies like the Analysis dll into one file, if you really need to.

Comment: i can't find the Publish artifact folder

Comment: Go to Build > Publish to set it